# MS Chart Control: Formatting Axis Labels

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, data-visualization, dundas

I have questions about formatting the axis labels of the MS ASP.NET chart control.  Before I dive into my questions, please take a look at this screenshot.

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, the axis labels are hard to read and appear to be bolded.  Now, my questions are:

- Which default chart properties cause the axis labels to not look like Arial 11px regular, i.e. bolding and close characters?
- How can the appearance of the axis labels be easier to read and cleaned up, i.e. regular font weight and separation between characters?

The responsible code is:

```
public Chart GetChart(ChartData chartDataData, IChartSettings settings)
{
    var chart = new Chart
    {
        BackColor = Color.Transparent,
        Height = settings.Height,
        Palette = ChartColorPalette.None,
        PaletteCustomColors = settings.PaletterCustomColors.ToArray(),
        Width = settings.Width
    };
    if (settings.ShowLegend)
    {
        chart.Legends.Add("Legend").Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
    }
    AddChartArea(chart);

    foreach (var seriesData in chartDataData.Series)
    {
        AddSeries(chart, seriesData, settings.ChartType);
    }

    chart.AlignDataPointsByAxisLabel();
    return chart;
}

private void AddChartArea(Chart chart)
{
    var area = new ChartArea();
    area.AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = -45;
    area.AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.Transparent;
    chart.ChartAreas.Add(area);
    area.AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = area.AxisY.LabelStyle.Font = new Font("Arial", 11, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}

private void AddSeries(Chart chart, SeriesData data, SeriesChartType chartType)
{
    var series = new Series
    {
        ChartType = chartType,
        Name = data.Name,
        ToolTip = data.Name,
        Url = data.Url
    };

    foreach (var pointData in data.Points)
    {
        AddPoint(series, pointData.XValue, pointData.YValue);
    }
    chart.Series.Add(series);
}

private void AddPoint(Series series, string xValue, float yValue)
{
    var point = new DataPoint
    {
        AxisLabel = xValue
    };
    point.SetValueXY(xValue, yValue);
    series.Points.Add(point);
}
```

where the code for the settings object is:

```
public static ChartSettings TaskSummary = new ChartSettings
{
    ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn,
    Height = Unit.Pixel(300),
    Width = Unit.Pixel(450),
    PaletterCustomColors = new[]
    {
        Color.FromArgb(191, 214, 151),
        Color.FromArgb(249, 255, 149),
        Color.FromArgb(191, 79, 75),
        Color.Green
    },
    ShowLegend = true
};
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you try **area.AxisX.LabelStyle.Font.Bold = false**?
Also, play with the  font size, i.e. change it to 12 and see how does it draw then...

Answer (score 5):

If you set BackColor of the chart to `Color.Transparent`, You need to set `AntiAliasing="Graphics"`.

Comment: Could you reference the documentation and explain why it works?

Comment: The best explanation for this fix I can find is in [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/64c7d890-c98b-4392-9ec9-1b4af3e24300/labels-bold-when-background-transparent?forum=MSWinWebChart). Quoted: "The issue lies 'deep' in the GDI+ used by the chart control... When you draw text in the image with transparent backgroundand you are using text anti-aliasing, GDI+ uses Black color as a default background to calculate anti-aliasing affect. You can either set solid color as a background or you can turn off text anti-aliasing using Chart.AntiAliasing=AntiAliasingStyles.Graphics;"